# UICollectionViewCell - Applying different CAGradientLayer to different UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, cagradientlayer

> TL;DR: Have 2 views (top and bottom) that need CAGradientLayer. Unexpected behavior is that only Top View displays gradient. Bottom doesn't display Gradient.

In our application, I have a view that has a UICollectionView as seen on the image: [image: Whole device]

For each UICollectionViewCell, I created a custom class to do the layout details. On the UICollectionViewCell, I have a "topBackground" and "bottomBackground", which are views that will content labels with info for each Cell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var topBackground: UIView! 
@IBOutlet weak var bottomBackground: UIView!
```

The Top and Bottom Views, Labels were displaying correctly and the constraints working.

We decided to add a gradient effect on the Top and Bottom View (see details on image, top gradient marked in red and bottom detail marked in yellow) [image].

For the code, we used the following:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        if !didLayout{                
             // Top View
            let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.frame = topBackground.frame
            gradientLayer.colors =
                [UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor, UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor]
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.9)
            topBackground.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
            topBackground.backgroundColor = .clear
            topBackground.alpha = 0.5

            // Bottom View
            let gradientLayerBottom: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayerBottom.frame = bottomBackground.frame
            gradientLayerBottom.colors =
                [UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor, UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor]
            gradientLayerBottom.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.9)
            gradientLayerBottom.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            bottomBackground.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayerBottom, at: 0)
            bottomBackground.backgroundColor = .clear
            bottomBackground.alpha = 0.5

            didLayout = true
        } else {
            print("already performed layout")
        }
    }
```

The variable `didLayout` is to avoid overlapping multiple gradients when scrolling the collection view.

Results:

1. The Top View is displaying the Gradient (Expected).
2. Bottom View is not displaying Gradient (Unexpected).

We know the bottom view is there with the constraints working, because if we change the color to other than `.clear`, it displays the other color. It's just `gradientLayerBottom` that is not being displayed.

Any ideas on how to get `gradientLayerBottom` to be displayed?

Comment: why are you inserting sublayer at `0`?

Comment: @Lu_ Tried to make sure it was the on the first position of `layer.sublayers`. Also tried `addSublayer`, instead of `insertSublayer(at:)` but same results.

Comment: and if you set up the same starting and ending points as in top gradient layer? it is weird, code looks ok

Comment: @Lu_ If I set the same start and end points, same result, the bottom one is not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
extension UIView{
    func setGradientBackgroundImage(colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop.cgColor, colorBottom.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Put in **UICollectionViewCell** class

```
class CollVwCell : UICollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var VwTop: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var VwBottom: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.VwTop.setGradientBackgroundImage(colorTop: UIColor.red, colorBottom: UIColor.white)
            self.VwBottom.setGradientBackgroundImage(colorTop: UIColor.white, colorBottom: UIColor.purple)
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: huh, that gradientLayer.frame = bounds did it!
I did:
 `gradientLayer.frame = topBackground.bounds`
and 
 `gradientLayerBottom.frame = bottomBackground.bounds` in the code we have and it worked. The problem was at the gradient layer frame.

Comment: Still I wonder why it worked for the top and not for the bottom.. And btw, forgot to call that on awakeFromNib, so I don't need to call the didLayout variable. Good reminder

Comment: @VictorSanchez You set the constraints by storyboard or programatically?

Comment: Tried both to see if it fixed the problem, ultimately left storyboard.

Comment: @VictorSanchez I think you have an issue with constraints because I tried same like you apply two different gradients to view inside **UICollectionViewCell** and it works fine with my answer. You can also see the Output image in my Updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, your answer worked fine before :) But it was not as problem of constraint. It was a problem of using topBackground.bound instead of topBackground.frame.